# How to get a column of nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like

```
{_id:xxx, xyz:[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]}
```

Now I want to query the first column data

```
x:[1,1,1]
```

How could I do it?

I know I can make the xyz

```
[{x:1,y:2,z:3},{x:1,y:2,z:3},{x:1,y:2,z:3}]
```

and use

```
find({},{x:'$xyz.x'})
```

Comment: You can use an aggregation array operator, like `$reduce` or `$map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      xyz: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$xyz",
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            x: { $first: "$$m" },
            y: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$m", 1 ] },
            z: { $last: "$$m" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      x: "$xyz.x"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/90Oy_bpH0NK)

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      x: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$xyz",
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            $first: "$$m"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "xyz"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fEVj0H-Zfdn)

Comment: It works.Are there a concise grammar to achieve it? Like using `find({}, { arrayElemAt: ['$xyz',1 ]})`

Comment: @wtyork I update my answer